# Explicitly Calling initComponent of extJS Class

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, extjs

There is probably a better way to do this and please provide guidance for me as to how to achieve it if possible but I was wondering if there was a way, on a Tab Click, to explicitly call that containers initComponent function? That is, the container that lives inside of that Tab Panel.

I currently have an initComponent in said panel that loads a Grid Panel with several Property Grids. The store changes when the user clicks a button on another Tab to update said panels store,so I'd like to call the initComponent again to refresh the Property Grids with the newly updated store.

Here is a code snippet of the other Tabs button that programatically switches tabs:

```
buttons: [{
    text: 'Configure',
    handler: function() {
      // Get name of role
      var roleList = Ext.getCmp('chefRoleRunListInformationGrid');

      if (roleList.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
        var roleName = roleList.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        roleName = roleName[0]['raw'][0];

        // Get Role Setup form
        Ext.getCmp('chefRoleSetupFormPanel').getForm().setValues({
            roleName: roleName
        });
      }

      var chefTabPanel = Ext.getCmp('chefTabPanel');
      chefTabPanel.setActiveTab(1);

      var chefRoleRunListInformationStore = Ext.getStore('chefRoleRunListInformationStore');
      var chefRequiredCookbooksGrid = Ext.getCmp('chefRequiredCookbooksGrid');
      var roleRunListInfoGrid = Ext.getCmp('chefRoleRunListInformationGrid');

      roleRunListInfoGridColumns = roleRunListInfoGrid.columns;

      chefRequiredCookbooksGrid.reconfigure(chefRoleRunListInformationStore);
    }
  }]
```

After the **chefTabPanel.setActiveTab(1)**, I'd like to call the initComponent function if possible to reload that tab with the new store.

Here is my code for the container that lives in said Tab:

```
Ext.define('chefCreateAndPinRolesLayoutContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 1,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            border: 1,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    Ext.create('chefRequiredCookbooksGridPanel')
                ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    Ext.create('chefRoleSetupFormPanel')
                ]
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            flex: 1,
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    Ext.create('chefOptionalCookbooksGridPanel')
                ]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: 'fit',
                items: [
                    Ext.create('chefAttributeGridContainer')
                ]
            }]
        }]
    }],

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        var chefRCS = Ext.create('chefRequiredCookbooksStore');

        var requiredCookbooksStore = Ext.getStore('chefRequiredCookbooksStore');
        var chefAttributesGridContainer = Ext.getCmp('chefAttributesGridContainer');

        requiredCookbooksStore.load({
            scope: this,
            callback: function(records, operation, success) {
                requiredCookbooksStore.data.each(function(item, index, totalItems) {
                    var cookbookName = item['raw'][0];
                    var cookbookVersion = item['raw'][1];

                    var attributesGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.property.Grid', {
                        width: 450,
                        id: cookbookName,
                        source: {
                            "Cookbook": cookbookName,
                            "Version": cookbookVersion
                        },
                        viewConfig: {
                            scroll: 'false',
                            style: {
                                overflow: 'auto',
                                overflowX: 'hidden'
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    chefAttributesGridContainer.add(attributesGrid);
                    chefAttributesGridContainer.doLayout();
                });
            }
        });

        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initComponent code isn't doing anything that *needs* to be in there. So why not just extract it into an `initStore` method and then just call it as you would any other method from the `initComponent` and when you change tabs.

Another suggestion unrelated to the question: avoid using `Ext.getCmp` it will lead to very tight coupling and bad architecture.

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it ended up working perfectly. Thanks a bunch Stuart!